# Is there any way to petition Hearthstone problems?

Tags: hearthstone

I was in Arena and the game timer stopped during the other player's turn, so I waited for an hour for it to fix itself, but it just stayed stuck. It looked like some kind of lag hack. Eventually, I gave up and quit and therefore lost the game.

Is there any way to petition something like this, since I lost money?

Note: this is not a disconnection issue; the game client did not need to be restarted, but continued operation throughout, only the game itself was bugged out, not the game client; the game client maintained the connection to the server the entire time

Comment: It's a disconnect on your side. It can be fixed by relaunching your hearthstone app.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, the answer is no. Blizzard does not reimburse any loses in the Area due to connection issues.

[Hearthstone Refund and Restoration Policy](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/hearthstone-refund-and-restoration-policy)

> **Arena Losses**
>
> Any losses due to disconnections during arena play cannot be reimbursed.

Comment: My connection was fine, the game was frozen either due to a hack or a bug. I was able to do actions requiring connection, such as access options and quit.

Comment: @TylerDurden Accessing options and quitting the game is always possible even without connection. The specific situation you encountered is definetly a disconnect. If you notice that you quickly have to quit the game and restart it. Hearthstone will then reconnect you to the game and you can continue playing.

Comment: @DenkerAffe It was not a connection problem.

Comment: @TylerDurden Maybe "disconnect" is not the right word for it, but the situation you described occurs when the game looses the connection to the Hearthstone-Server. This can happen even when your internet connection is working completly fine. It might be a temporary problem on the battle.net site or another random issue. Restarting the client and reconnecting as I described in my previous comment fixes the problem most of the time.

Comment: Blizzard has been having some DDoS issues in the last few weeks, it's possible you were D/Ced during one of them.

Comment: It is a disconnect, just a buggy form of it. Usually you'll get it in mobile apps, where the enemy's turn lasts forever. It won't say you've disconnected or whatever, but it still is a form of disconnect. You can do almost all actions you can normally do, even emoting is possible but the opponent won't see it. I've gotten it various times myself also.